# Retrieve a row from multiple tables on Oracle [one or more tables are empty]

Tags: sql, oracle

When having multiple tables with different columns, I would like to add all of them as one record. However, when one of them doesn't have records,
the other records retrieved from the other tables are not shown. How can I show the results of the remaining tables? For example, I have three
tables with one catalogue. Suppose that Table A doesn't have records and table B and C have. How can I show the results for these tables (Table B and C)? Even when Table A doesn't have records.

For example:

```
Table A
 RECN
 FNAME

TABLE B
 RECN
 DATE

TABLE C
 RECN
 ATTR1

Table CAT
 RECN
 LABEL

 SELECT TA.*,TB.*,TC.*
 FROM
 (SELECT A.RECN, A.FNAME, CAT.LABEL
 FROM  A, CAT
 WHERE A.RECN= CAT.RECN) TA,
 (SELECT B.RECN, B.DATE, CAT.LABEL
 FROM B, CAT
 WHERE B.RECN=CAT.RECN) TB,
 (SELECT C.RECN, C.ATTR1, CAT.LABEL
 FROM C, CAT
 WHERE C.RECN=CAT.RECN) TC
```

Now, I am obtaining an empty row, but I have to show the values of the tables which include values.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show sample input/output data?  Also, your join syntax looks strange (`A.RECN= CAT.RECN`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`.  In addition, the subqueries -- while not a problem -- are not needed.  In fact, your `JOIN` syntax is wrong.  Here is what the query should look like:

```
SELECT A.RECN, A.FNAME, CAT.LABEL, 
       B.RECN, B.DATE, CAT.LABEL,
       C.RECN, C.ATTR1, CAT.LABEL
FROM TA LEFT JOIN 
     TB
     ON B.RECN = CAT.RECN LEFT JOIN
     TC
     C.RECN = CAT.RECN;
```